# Alignment of if-else notation

Tags: vertical-alignment, ifthenelse

I have three if-else condition notations one after the other. I want to align their brackets together but can't do so.

```
    \begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
  \texttt{Chapter 1} \\
  \texttt{Chapter 2}\\
  \texttt{Chapter 3}
\end{rcases}
\text{Vector algebra, Simple Differentiation and Integration}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
  \texttt{Chapter 4} \\
  \texttt{Chapter 5}\\
  \texttt{Chapter 6}
\end{rcases}
\text{Vector Calculus}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{rcases}
  \texttt{Chapter 7} \\
\end{rcases}
\text{Vector calculus and Tensor algebra}
\end{equation*}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you want a `NiceTabular` (see the manual of `nicematrix`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{NiceTabular}{ll}
  Chapter 1 & \Block{3-1}{Vector algebra, Simple Differentiation and Integration} \\
  Chapter 2 & \\
  Chapter 3 & \\
  \\
  Chapter 4 & \Block{3-1}{Vector calculus} \\
  Chapter 5 & \\
  Chapter 6 & \\
  \\
  Chapter 7 & Vector calculus and Tensor algebra \\
\CodeAfter
  \SubMatrix.{1-1}{3-1}\}
  \SubMatrix.{5-1}{7-1}\}
  \SubMatrix.{9-1}{9-1}\}
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 How are you active so early :)

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner That's late, actually.